# Problem receiving response from node server using ajax post request

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I have written a http server using node js

```
var sys = require("sys"),
    http = require("http"),
    url = require("url"),
    path = require("path"),
    fs = require("fs");



http.createServer(function(request, res) {

    var parsed_url = url.parse(request.url);
    var uri = parsed_url.pathname;
   if(uri === "/test"){

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'});

      request.addListener('data', function (chunk) {
          var data = eval("(" + chunk + ")");
          console.log(data[0].id);
      })
      request.addListener('end', function() {
          console.log('end triggered');
          res.write("Post data");
          res.end();
      }); 
   }
}).listen(8080);
```

and i am trying to send back response of ajax request but i am unable to receive any response. Here is the code for ajax request ,

```
    var myhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/test";

    var data = [{"a":"1"},{"b":"2"},{"c":"3"}];

    var dataJson = JSON.stringify(data);
    myhttp.open('POST', url, true);
    myhttp.send(dataJson);
    myhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {        
        if ((myhttp.readyState == 4) && (myhttp.status == 200)){
            alert(myhttp.responseText);
        }
        else if ((myhttp.readyState == 4) && (myhttp.status != 200))
        {
            console.log("Error in Connection");
        }
```

Can anyone help me what i am doing wrong ...

Thanks
Vinay

Comment: Also in chrome I am getting error : Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to read the data in a different way. Posted data arrives on a node server in chunks (the 'data' event), that have to be collected until the 'end' event fires. Inside this event, you are able to access your payload.

```
var body = '';

request.addListener('data', function (chunk) {
  body += chunk;
});

request.addListener('end', function() {
  console.log(body);
  res.write('post data: ' + body);
});
```

Additionaly, there seem to be some issues with your client-side code (especially concerning the status-code checks), but i can't really help you with those as i always work with frameworks like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) to manage async requests.

If you want to build reliable node.js servers for web use, i highly recommend the high-performance HTTP-Framework [Express](http://expressjs.com/). It takes away alot of the pain when developing a web-based server application in node and is maintained actively.

Comment: That problem is resolved by replacing the header with res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/javascript', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*' }); But know problem is it doesnt works in chrome error is : Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Answer (score 3):

Your code is almost right but on your code sample you have

```
console.log(data[0].id)
```

the **data** object has **no** property **id** so if you only have

```
console.log(data[0])
```

there you have a response like

```
{ a: '1' }
```

therefore you can access the property **a** by doing

```
console.log(data[0].a);
```

**UPDATED Updated with a full example**

One more thing is that you are using **eval** and node comes with **JSON.parse** bundle with it so the snippet below is how i made it work

File: app.js

```
var sys = require("sys"),
    http = require("http"),
    url = require("url"),
    path = require("path"),
    fs = require("fs");



http.createServer(function(request, res) {    
   var parsed_url = url.parse(request.url);
   var uri = parsed_url.pathname;

   if(uri === "/test"){

      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'});
      request.addListener('data', function (chunk) {
          // removed this - eval("(" + chunk + ")");
          var data = JSON.parse(chunk);    
          console.log(data[0].a);
      })
      request.addListener('end', function() {
          console.log('end triggered');
          res.write("Post data");
          res.end();
      });              

   } else if(uri === "/") {
       fs.readFile("./index.html",function(err, data){
         if(err) throw err;
          res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
          res.end(data);
       });    
   }

}).listen(8080);
```

On the same directory create a file index.html with the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
         var myhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       var url = "http://localhost:8080/test";

       var data = [{"a":"1"},{"b":"2"},{"c":"3"}];
       var dataJson = JSON.stringify(data);

       myhttp.open('POST', url, true);
       myhttp.send(dataJson);
       myhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {        
           if ((myhttp.readyState == 4) && (myhttp.status == 200)){
               alert(myhttp.responseText);
           }
           else if ((myhttp.readyState == 4) && (myhttp.status != 200))
           {
               console.log("Error in Connection");
           }
       }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

That is a complete working example of what you want.

With regards to the same origin policy issues you were having is mainly due to the fact that you cant POST data between 2 different domains via ajax unless you use some tricks with iframes but that is another story.

Also i think is good for anyone to understand the backbone of a technology before moving into frameworks so fair play to you.

good luck

Comment: hey, it works on firefox when i replaced the header with  res.writeHead(200, {
   'Content-Type': 'text/javascript',
   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
  }); but on chrome i am getting errorRequest header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. you have any clue how to resolve in chrome.

Comment: Are running the examples on the same host and port ? If not you must use **jsonp** when making your ajax request.

Comment: Thanks Joao , Actually problem was of permissions for request headers that need to be set for webkit based browsers, so doing Access-Control-Allow-Headers - 'Content-type' in response headers solved this.As webkit breaks down the ajax request in two parts..so this solved by seeing webkit cors :-)